# How to create multiple tabs or sheets or pages in mxGraph?

Tags: javascript, mxgraph, jgraph, draw.io

`Draw.io` has the feature of multiple `pages` with a tab view in the bottom.

But to integrate that into `mxgraph` graph editor, it seems like an overkill.

I'm looking for a simpler solution or some sort of workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for sort of workaround I have solution. Creates the graph inside the given container using a model with a custom root and two layers. Layers can also be added dynamically using 
`const layer = model.add(root, new mxCell()).`

```
const root = new mxCell();
const  layer0 = root.insert(new mxCell());
const layer1 = root.insert(new mxCell()); 
const model = new mxGraphModel(root);
```

Just look [example](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/layers.html)